# Create the following semantic difference type of survey item in LimeSurvey

Tags: limesurvey

I am using LimeSurvey Version 2.50+ Build 160202, and trying to do with following type of questions. I am new to LimeSurvey and tried to find a solution but stuck somewhere, tried online resources but that did not exactly solve my problem.

I found some posts on manual.limesurvey.org/Workarounds:_Quest...one_and_two_sided.29 and manual.limesurvey.org/Question_type_-_Array but I did not get exactly how to implement it on survey.

I want to create survey with the questions like

Q. Which color do you like? selecting 1 is equal, selecting radio button on either side is higher preferred against another (scale 9 to 1 to 9 radio button type)

[image: Red...Blue]

Answer (score 1):

Array question type : Red|Blue for sub question : [LimeSurve Manual](https://manual.limesurvey.org/Question_type_-_Array#General_description)
:  [Test link for public](http://demonstration.sondages.pro/587956) (with the lss file inside)